# Haskell: Matching String Prefixes against List

Tags: haskell, lexer

I've been learning some Haskell lately, and I thought a lexer might be a fun project. I'm using [this ANSI C Yacc grammar](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) as a guide.

The general program structure is:

```hs
lex :: [Char] -> Maybe [Token]
lex s =
  case tokenize([], s) of
    Just (tokens, []) -> Just tokens
    _ -> Nothing

tokenize :: ([Token], [Char]) -> Maybe ([Token], [Char])
```

Where `tokenize` builds a list of tokens. **I'm having trouble thinking of a suitable structure for `tokenize`.** For example, to match keywords like `int`, I could write:

```hs
tokenize (toks, 'i':'n':'t':' ':rest) = tokenize (toks++[TokenKeyword IntK], rest)
```

But this seems like a terrible way to do things. Is there a way to pattern match against elements in a list? Could I create a list of all keywords, and attempt to match them as prefixes of the input string?

Comment: Matching on prefixes won't get you very far, because some tokens won't be predefined strings - for example numbers or identifiers.

Comment: Right, of course prefix matching would not cover everything. I was talking specifically about reserved keywords

Comment: Perhaps [regex-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative) will suit your needs.

Comment: You should probably learn how to use some parsec library.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their input. To clarify my question further, I would like to limit how much I use parsing/regex libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match based on a string prefix, you could use the [ViewPatterns extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns). This extension can be enabled by passing -XViewPatterns to the compiler, by running `:set -XViewPatterns` in ghci, or by putting `{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}` at the top of the file.

Then, you can write a function `matchPrefix` (not 100% optimal, as it does iterate over `prefix` twice):

```
matchPrefix :: String -> String -> Maybe String
matchPrefix prefix result
  | and (zipWith (==) prefix result) = Just (drop (length prefix) result)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

And then use it in a pattern like the following:

```
startsWithInt :: String -> Bool
startsWithInt (matchPrefix "int " -> Just rest) = True
startsWithInt _ = False
```

If you wanted to match based on a list of tokens, and get out the rest of the string and which token matched, you could do that by modifying `matchPrefix` to do that instead.